# How can I make geom_line to work with the y as counts?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a plot that compares my LASSO and Ridge results.
The data that I have is

```
bias_data <- data.frame(
  bias = abs(as.vector(biases)),
  type = rep(c("Ridge sample", "Ridge population", "LASSO sample", "LASSO population"), 100)
)
```

This works perfectly when I do

```
ggplot(bias_data, aes(bias,  fill = type)) +
  geom_hist()
```

with the y axis as count, but it's not intuitive so I want to do a geom_line,
but this returns

```
Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example `biases` is not found.  In the `aes`, it is different for `geom_hist` and `geom_line`.  Can you show your `geom_line` code as well

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not intuitive"? What is the goal? What do you want the line to represent?

Comment: If you want to visualise the distribution with a line instead of a histogram you could have a look at `geom_freqpoly`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work with `geom_line()` is explained in the error: `geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y`; you must supply `geom_line()` with both an `x` and `y` aesthetic, unlike `geom_histogram()` which only requires an `x` aesthetic.

`geom_histogram()` is special, and doesn't require a `y` aesthetic because it does the work for you and counts the number of observations in each group of `x` that you specify. However, `geom_line()` (and many other `geom_*` functions), require you to explicitly provide both `x` and `y` values.

So, the short answer is that your `geom_line()` code doesn't work because you have only provided an `x` aesthetic. To plot the count data, you must calculate the count data yourself, and supply that as a `y` aesthetic.

Using `mtcars` as an example:

```
# histogram of counts per 'cyl' and  'am'
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, colour = factor(am)))+
  geom_histogram(position = 'dodge', binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

To plot these count values as a line, we must calculate the count per group, using `n()` as the counting function, and `group_by()` and `summarise()` to summarise the data for a single value per group.

```
# first calculate the total count per group
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(
    count = n()
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> mtcars_count} # this saves the count data


mtcars_count

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl    am count
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     0     3
2     4     1     8
3     6     0     4
4     6     1     3
5     8     0    12
6     8     1     2


# then plot the line data
mtcars_count %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, count, colour = factor(am)))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

If you want to get fancy, you can even combine the two plots into one. Note we use `position_dodge()` with `geom_line()` so it aligns with the dodged bars of `geom_histogram()`.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_histogram(data = mtcars, aes(cyl, colour = factor(am)), position = 'dodge', binwidth = 1)+
  geom_line(data = mtcars_count, aes(cyl, count, colour = factor(am)), position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]